# Classes in AngularFire2: how to handle $key

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

Currently working on my first AngularFire2 app. 
I have Typescript classes that match my structure in the firebase.

my firebase structure

```
-players
 |-playerkey
   |-name
```

and my class is

```
export class Player {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}
```

If i want the playerkey in my player object i can't just add public key:string to the constructor because this would prevent me from pushing any player object to the firebase.

Is there any proper way to use AngularFire2 with my own classes and objects?

Should I always use  the FirebaseObjectObservable to pass my playerobject between services? As far as I know, I can't create a FirebaseObjectObservable by myself. I have to get it from the firebase.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

**`player.ts`**

```
export class Player {
    constructor(public $key: string, public name: string) {
    }

    static fromJson({ $key, name }) {
        return new Player($key, name);
    }

    static fromJsonArray(json: any[]): Player[] {
        return json.map(Player.fromJson);
    }
}
```

Get all players with player instance.

**`playerService.ts`**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2';
import { Player } from 'path/to/player.ts'

@Injectable()
export class playerService {
    constructor(private afd: AngularFireDatabase) {}

    getPlayers(): Observable<Player[]> {
        return this.afd.list(`players`).map(Player.fromJsonArray);
    }

    savePlayer(player: Player): Observable<any> {
        // your code to save a player
    }
}
```

Add this method in your component

**`yourComponent.ts`**

```
savePlayer(name: string) {
    let player = Player.fromJson({ name: name });
    delete player.$key;

    this.playerService().savePlayer(player).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Your Player constructor? That is the only thing we differ on really. I am storing the `FirebaseObjectObservable` that was emitted.  My constructor is `(private dbObject: FirebaseObjectObservable)`.  It is basically a wrapper around that inner object. (Actually I have a dedicated interface for that inner observable). I would say `get key(){ return this.dbObject.$key}`.  Does anyone know the pros and cons of our variance? It is like Transfer vs Wrap

Comment: @Clark Can you post your answer so they can compare our implementation? Thanks

Comment: Has the `Observable<>` the same functions as the `FirebaseObjectObservable<>` and the `FirebaseListObservable<>`, do changes in the db tribbe a UI update if i use it?